# Kendo MVC File Upload - Current HTML jQuery Object - On Select Event - jQuery

Tags: jquery, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-upload

How to get data attribute value on file select event.

Note: Here i am trying to resolve current html to get jQuery object

```
$("#gridAttachment").find("input.fileUpload").each(function (index) {
       $(this).kendoUpload({ select: onAttachmentSelect });    
});

function onAttachmentSelect(e) {
       //debugger;
       var id = $('thisObj').data('id');
       //Some other Data Attribute Value

       //After validation jQuery AJAX Upload
};
```

Comment: Here i am trying to resolve current html to get jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onAttachmentSelect(e) {
    //debugger;
    var fileUploadData = $(e.sender.element[0]).data();
    var id = fileUploadData.data('id');

    //jQuery AJAX Upload
};
```

Comment: Or just `var id = $(e.sender.element[0]).data('id');` in any case this has been asked and answered on lots of previous occasions.